# How to play videos from youtube, metacafe etc in a native iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, youtube-api

I get a feed which consists of a URL pointing to the videos from sites like youtube, metacafe etc.

I found this [post](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application) suggesting how to use UIWebView to load the video into the app. However I don't want the video to play in full screen mode. I want it to play in the frame I have allocated for it.

1. How do I make the youtube video which is loaded by embedding html into the uiwebview play in the frame allocated to it  and not in full screen mode?
2. How do we play videos from sites like metacafe and comedy central and other sites where url doesn't point to a file but instead loads a player if pasted on browser.
3. Are there any applications which have achieved to play the same as a native iphone app?

Any help in this regards would be greatly helpful.

EDIT:
I want to know how do we play a video from the url say - http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/xe1l96

I would like to know how to play the video in the webview itself.  I want to use the space around it to display other information.  Currently it forces full screen mode.

Safari is able to play dailymotion and vimeo videos by lauching the quicktime player. So I would like to know how to redirect to play the videos using quicktime player.

How do I play videos from youtube and metacafec in a native iphone app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     UIWebView  *wbView = (UIWebView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
     NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, 64.0, 64.0];
    [wbView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];



}
 "url" is the youtube video url


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [category_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIWebView  *wbView = (UIWebView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *btn = [self findButtonInView:wbView];
    [btn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}


// detecting the play button on the you tube video thumbnail

- (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view {
    UIButton *button = nil;

    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return (UIButton *)view;
    }

    if (view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            button = [self findButtonInView:subview];
            if (button) return button;
        }
    }

    return button;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {
    UIButton *button = [self findButtonInView:_webView];
    [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Basically, i had to show thumbnails in table cell

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Does this play in the full screen mode or in a frame which is equal to size of the web view? I think it plays in the full screen mode. Other than youtube how do we play videos from metacafe, dailmotion, vimeo?

Comment: size of webview.if you found this usefule.please upvote the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015165/playing-a-video-file-from-server-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: for metcafe you can try this above link

Comment: Hey swastik, i would have upvoted anyways. Rite now i have set the size of webview to 300*200 but its still playing in full screen. But i havent tried your approach. Will try it immediately. Probably if it works for me i will accept this answer, though i need to find ways to play videos from as many sites as possible and make a generic way to play them.

Comment: Its not playing in the area where i create the webview. Can you post your screen shot ? Or give some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Praveen,

Your video will always play full screen on iPhone & iPod. The mentioned flag (`allowsInlineMediaPlayback`) only works on iPad...

Comment: Yup, do you have know how to make videos from other sites play on ipod/iphone?

Comment: Using an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and setting the `contentURL` should do the trick. As long as the URL is reachable and the video is in a format iOS can play.

Comment: Yup the problem is the all urls are nt in the format iOs can play, but when loaded in safari they can be played. However there are no APIs to get the url in the format they are loaded into safari(pointing to mp4).

Comment: Praveen, pardon me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you're trying to leech video's from some site you don't run and has no API. If this is the case you should be more resourceful yourself :-)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is my app would want to play the url user's tweet, however few sites dont provide API to get the content url playable by iphone. However i am of the opinion that using html 5 embed tags it can still be played. So i was looking for a solution where we can embed such urls into a webview. And NO i am not trying to leech video's', all i have is the url from the tweet.

Comment: So what you might want is something like the YouTube solution but then for HTML5 video tags.
Did you try something like:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3792/discussion-between-maarten-wolzak-and-praveen-s)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is easy. Just set the UIWebView's `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property to YES.

The other stuff is just a flash player that wraps around a video. It's going to be harder, and probably not worth it without the backing of the site in question.

Good luck, and if you need any more help just comment/edit your question.

Comment: When i set the property allowsInlineMediaPlayback to YES, it still opens up a new full screen mode. Also can i play other videos similarly? Full screen mode will also do but i need to explore all the options to play video i.e -- in a frame say 320 * 200 and not full screen, so that i can use the other part of the screen to display information about the video.