# How to play video in iphone sdk 4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I played video in iphone by using this code

```
-(IBAction)btnNew_clicked:(id)sender {  

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];}

-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification  {       
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];  }
```

by using this code movie player opens for 1 second and then close automatically, without playing the file.

I checked the video file it is correct but it is not playing in iphone sdk 4.0.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see this question-

[Playing a video file from server in an Iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015165/playing-a-video-file-from-server-in-an-iphone-app/5015348#5015348)

trry out following code and don't forget to add MediaPlayer.framework and must import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
    [player play];

}
```

Comment: This post shows how to play video file in WebView my question is change. Please provide sufficient suggestion.

Comment: @Anderson- its working in my test project, try the updated Answer!

Comment: Your code does not working in my device. Can u please send me your test project in zip format, so i can test it on my device. Currently i am using iphone 3gs with ios 4.0 on it. Thanks for giving suggestion.