# Issues in playing m4v video from ftp server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
[myplayer setContentURL:theMovieURL];
[myplayer play];
```

Whenever I play nay video It just plays 1-2 seconds and then the player stops.
Then When I again press play I again continues and stops again.

I think it must be because of slow speed. but it does not even show any loading status or similar thing neither does it again starts playing automatically after a little pause while streaming like in you tube videos..

I am looking at it from last 20 hours and failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015165/playing-a-video-file-from-server-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: @Prince I have tried implementing hte html code in the link provided. But it too have the same problem... When internet speed is slow.. It goes into pause state and we have to press the playbutton everytime :(